# How to add labels and forward an incoming email in one click?

Tags: gmail

I forward every invoice received by email (in Gmail) to my accounting platform. Also, I add a couple of labels/tags to these emails to keep track of the processing.
Does Gmail allow me to create some kind of custom action that I could configure (ala Outlook rules) so that I would simply have to click one button to perform all these operations in one shot?