# AVERAGEIF on last N rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

This seems pretty simple but I can't find how to do it.

I keep a Google Sheet where I add several times a day new lines as following :

```
  | A     | B   | C   |
  | ---   | --- | --- |
1 | John  | 10  | 50  |
2 | Peter | 20  | 70  | 
3 | John  | 14  |     |
4 | Peter | 12  | 82  |
5 | John  | 5   | 55  |
```

I'm trying to get the average rating of the last N lines for a given name.
That way I can send a report to "name" every now and then with an average of his N last ratings.

Comment: Please check the [edited question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/149911/4) and confirm it is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

Use a query to get the last `N` entries of a particular name and then get the average based on column `C`.

The trick here is to reverse the matrix: `sort(A1:C5,ROW(A1:A5),False)` so you get the last `N` rows.

**Solution:**

```
=INDEX(QUERY(
     QUERY(sort(A1:C5,ROW(A1:A5),False),"select * where Col1 contains 'John' limit 2"),
"select avg(Col2),avg(Col3)"),2,0)
```

this will calculate **both** the averages of the last `N` (`2`) entries of a particular name:

**Example**: `Peter` last `2` entries:

[image]

**Example**: `John` last `2` entries:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not exactly what I need.

this will calculate the average for John for N larger than 3, but I need the average of exactly John last N grades.

Different names don't have same number of grades so if I can't specify 'last 30 grades' it will return me more grade for 1 pupil than for another, and I need exactly the average of the last 30.

Comment: @FrancisKabalou check again the answer.

Comment: Instead of `3` and `John` you can use input from other cells by using their reference.

Comment: @Marios, the question was not displayed correctly.

Comment: @Marios Also. You could probably write a script for [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149904/how-to-add-labels-and-forward-an-incoming-email-in-one-click) question. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry If I didn't express well the question or what I tried already. I think the answer given by Mario will give me the average of John's grades in the last N lines, and not the average of the N last John's grades.

Maybe I could find a way to add a column with a True/False which would be true for the last N grade of each pupil, and then do a simple averageifs on it, but I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: @FrancisKabalou please see my updated answer. If it solved your question, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the tick button to the left of the answer.

Comment: @FrancisKabalou So what your expected result would be for John at lines 3 and 5?

Comment: @marikamitsos okay, now I think it is perfect. Check my answer :)

Comment: wow, works perfectly ! Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @FrancisKabalou I am very glad it finally worked out! :)

Comment: That is great @Marios One could also consider [taking the parameters out of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3W5I.png).